# Adding buttons to listview android xamarin

Tags: android, listview, button, xamarin

I have created a standard listview and I have populated it with text. Is it possible to add one or two buttons to each row  which will then perform some sort of function?

Comment: I posted my answer below in that layout i used two text view instead of that you just add your designed layout in that custom adaptor

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible you need to create custom layout for the row,
 see this 
[example](http://looksok.wordpress.com/tag/listview-item-with-button/)

Answer (score 0):

You just use this custom adapter in your Listview creation and then you will write your code in this block...

use this code in your activity...

```
  CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, mListItems);
  mPullRefreshListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And then here you replace your Layout....

```
  public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sample> {

public ArrayList<Sample> mlist;
public Context context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Sample> mlist) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.mlist = mlist;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(Sample item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public Sample getItem(int position) {
    return mlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);// Replace your
                                                            // layout....
    TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    text1.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem1());
    text2.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem2());
    text2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // you just put your Logic here And use this custom adapter to
            // load your Data By using this particular custom adapter to
            // your listview
            // Change your imageview here

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

}
```

Comment: So can you not add a button? Do you have to use a 2nd text view?

Comment: You can flow above answer. Instead of using textview you can add buttons in your xml(here it is R.layout.listitem). Or you can use this  http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/ tutorial. Instead of image view you can add button.

Comment: @BrianPeach You just use your own designed layout you will replace in that listitem ...That is all

Comment: @NaveenKumar how does this work with Xamarin as Super doesnt relate